# how to 'Mark as read ' a mail of GMail with C# .NET?

Tags: c#, gmail

I want to make a gmail notifier in C#. I accessed Unread mail list by parsing Gmail atom feed. But i want to add a feature to my app so that user can directly **mark any mail as read**. Any one has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

You can use an IMAP LIBRARY to access GMAIL with C#. IMAP will support marking messages as **read** out of the box.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx) is a project implementing an IMAP client with C#. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c) is a StackOverflow question addressing the issue of IMAP access with C#.

Hope it helps.