# Accessing Gmail accounts from C#

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, pop3

I've tried some code I found here:

- [Access Gmail](http://www.revenmerchantservices.com/page/read-gmail.aspx)

I am unable to get it to work and get the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 209.85.227.109:995

I have POP enabled on all my Gmail accounts.

I can use third party tools like [this sidebar gadget](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=0ab7b1be-4f2d-4f30-aa55-f270d53b9c99&bt=1), so I don't think port 995 is blocked.

Any thoughts on what I can try next?

Comment: Consider using IMAP instead of POP3, it works much better.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101522/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Please take a read of the following document:

- [POP3 Email Client (.NET 2.0)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can otherwise read your mail through RSS feeds.

**https://username:password@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom**

**https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/labelname**
You can also read feeds with specific label.

Answer (score 1):

You can telnet 209.85.227.109 995
and make sure that you get blank screen. This ensures that your computer is able to connect Gmail server. contact your system admin to unblock the port 995 or gmail smtp/pop server.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found here: [Reading emails from Gmail in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/550198)

But before this, you need to configure your Gmail setting to enable the Imap and third party mail clients. 
To do so, you can follow the steps from this page: [How to Enable IMAP/POP3/SMTP for Gmail Account?](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/how-to-enable-imap-pop3-smtp-gmail-account.html)