# Reading emails from Gmail in C#

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, imap

I am trying to read emails from Gmail. I have tried every API / open source project I can find,  and can not get any of them working.

Does anyone have a sample of working code that will allow me to authenticate and download emails from a Gmail account?

Final working version posted below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/550198

Comment: You can access Gmail via via IMAP.
See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c

Comment: @Kiquenet Final working version posted below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/550198

Comment: Mark as final answer then.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Using the library from: https://github.com/pmengal/MailSystem.NET

Here is my complete code sample:

### Email Repository

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ActiveUp.Net.Mail;

namespace GmailReadImapEmail
{
    public class MailRepository
    {
        private Imap4Client client;

        public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
        {
            if (ssl)
                Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            else
                Client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            Client.Login(login, password);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast<Message>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetUnreadMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "UNSEEN").Cast<Message>();
        }

        protected Imap4Client Client
        {
            get { return client ?? (client = new Imap4Client()); }
        }

        private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase)
        {
            Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
            MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase);
            return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReadImap()
{
    var mailRepository = new MailRepository(
                            "imap.gmail.com",
                            993,
                            true,
                            "yourEmailAddress@gmail.com",
                            "yourPassword"
                        );

    var emailList = mailRepository.GetAllMails("inbox");

    foreach (Message email in emailList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<p>{0}: {1}</p><p>{2}</p>", email.From, email.Subject, email.BodyHtml.Text);
        if (email.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MimePart attachment in email.Attachments)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<p>Attachment: {0} {1}</p>", attachment.ContentName, attachment.ContentType.MimeType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Another example, this time using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

```
public class MailRepository : IMailRepository
{
    private readonly string mailServer, login, password;
    private readonly int port;
    private readonly bool ssl;

    public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
    {
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
        this.port = port;
        this.ssl = ssl;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUnreadMails()
    {
        var messages = new List<string>();

        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect(mailServer, port, ssl);

            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            client.Authenticate(login, password);

            // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...
            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
            var results = inbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, SearchQuery.Not(SearchQuery.Seen));
            foreach (var uniqueId in results.UniqueIds)
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uniqueId);

                messages.Add(message.HtmlBody);

                //Mark message as read
                //inbox.AddFlags(uniqueId, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

        return messages;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllMails()
    {
        var messages = new List<string>();

        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect(mailServer, port, ssl);

            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            client.Authenticate(login, password);

            // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...
            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
            var results = inbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, SearchQuery.NotSeen);
            foreach (var uniqueId in results.UniqueIds)
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uniqueId);

                messages.Add(message.HtmlBody);

                //Mark message as read
                //inbox.AddFlags(uniqueId, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[Test]
public void GetAllEmails()
{
    var mailRepository = new MailRepository("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, "YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com", "YOURPASSWORDHERE");
    var allEmails = mailRepository.GetAllMails();

    foreach(var email in allEmails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(email);
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(allEmails.ToList().Any());
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code, it compiles okay. But when I try to run, it got stuck for more than 5 minutes at the line mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase) via call GetUnreadMails. I only have 53 unread emails in my inbox. Any explanation?

Comment: I have not used this code since around the time of the OP. However, I fired up my unit test and it did retrieve my unreal emails (count=12). Test took approximately 66 seconds to run.

Comment: I have build the console application in c# using above code, everything fixed but gmail not allowing to login. Here is my error message:- ** failed : * NO [WEBALERT https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvAEG9lCWQe-Z6jvg-VMfEebVSPMJ8KdejU_3XhJcIi8AlYr4JO8PCByg3WoSo2JePxUXqnYowDn-O5NCkPcL62ywOQgBtk9mZEZQn6YxbKdafk2MyUtx29A85MOF9Duz3MHYdNIHjSAl_p9S2QjchFBIiVxUDAiZOBsbz3Lk] Web login required.
161116082452398 NO [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)**

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to enable "Less secure apps" with your gmail account, if that is an option for you. I did that, and now the code works. Read more here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I have copy pasted your code. Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in ActiveUp.Net.Imap4.dll when it tries get mail via GetAllMails("inbox");

Comment: what is ? IMailRepository. Mailkit does not have that Interface.

Comment: @Nulle This was from my code base. You can remove that interface for your own use-case.

Comment: can I limit GetAllMails by date?

Comment: @Toolkit Yes, it is definitely possible. You should really post a different question on this site though.

Comment: @Seany84 thanks for your nice sample codes. I tried to use `MailSystem.NET` , but has error on Client.Log() : BAD Too many arguments provided . My password contains spaces and this login fails!

Comment: When I try to read the UnreadEmail I get the exception on GetMail method with exception like index out of exception

Comment: Could not load type System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
Microsoft has obsolesced that library.  Code changes to ActiveUp are needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.certificatepolicy?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 25):

You **don't** need any extra **3rd Party Libraries** if a summary of the 20 most recent emails is sufficient for you. You can read the data from API that Gmail has provided here: https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

The response in **XML** format can be handled by the code below:

```cs
try {
    const string emailAddress = "YourEmail";
    // App Password, not password
    // See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en
    const string appPassword = "YourAppPassword";

    string response;
    string title;
    string summary;
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // Logging in Gmail server to get data
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{emailAddress}:{appPassword}")));

    // Reading data and converting to string
    response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom");

    // Remove XML namespace to simplify parsing/selecting nodes
    response = response.Replace(@"<feed version=""0.3"" xmlns=""http://purl.org/atom/ns#"">", @"<feed>");

    // Loading into an XML so we can get information easily
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(response);

    // Amount of emails
    string nr = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"/feed/fullcount").InnerText;

    // Reading the title and the summary for every email
    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDocument.SelectNodes(@"/feed/entry")) {
        title = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
        summary = node.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText;

        Console.WriteLine($"> {title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{summary}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show($"Error retrieving mails: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach, and it's important to many people, is that you can't get the full text of the message body via the ATOM route.

Comment: There is another method of getting the route of ATOM with XML. You just have to create a namespace for XML form and you can access it easily! Read about that and you will understand because its no difference from this! :)

Comment: Then please illustrate how you would retrieve the message body.

Comment: nr is undefined

Comment: Love your answer - Does every single thing need a NuGet package to be viable these days.  Is that what we've become :(

Comment: I got a 401 Unauthorized error. How should I fix that?

Comment: another problem with this model is that, you cannot get entire mailbox information. max 20 email details. No more than that.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried POP3 [Email Client with full MIME Support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx?fid=341657) ?

If you don't it's a very good example for you. As an alternativ;

[OpenPop.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)

> .NET class library in C# for communicating with POP3 servers. Easy to
>   use but yet powerful. Includes a robust MIME parser backed by several
>   hundred test cases. For more information, visit our project homepage.

[Lumisoft](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/Download/Downloads/Net/)

Comment: Thanks, somehow I managed to try every C# non-working POP3 email client :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can also try [Mail.dll IMAP client](https://www.limilabs.com/mail).

It supports all [Gmail IMAP protocol extensions](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/gmail-extensions-in-mail-dll):

- Thread ID,
- Message ID,
- Labels,
- Localized folder names,
- Google search syntax
- OAuth authentication.

Please note that Mail.dll is a commercial product, I've developed.

Comment: I have no budget to pay for this as there are open-source and free alternatives available.

Comment: any free version, not premium? Any open source alternative ?