# Fetch both read and unread mails from Gmail

Tags: c#

I want to fetch all the mails (both read and unread) from my gmail account. What should be the best approach for this since I have 2GB of mails in by account.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/2132796) answer?

Comment: What you tried - The question is very broad.

Comment: I've tried OpenPop.NET but it is fetching only unread mails.

Answer (score 0):

OpenPop.NET is an open source implementation of a POP3 client.It allows easy access to email on a POP3 server in a matter of minutes.You can use this dll to get all the mails.

Here is the link to http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/ to download dll and you will get some examples here http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php

Edit: To get all the messages

```
int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();//client is POP3Client instance

List<Message> _allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)    
     _allMessages .Add(client.GetMessage(i));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I've already tried this. I'm getting only unread mails not the read ones.

Comment: I've used the same code but only unread mails are recieved :(

Comment: The above code is used to get all the mails(read and unread)<http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleFetchAllMessages.php>. If you want to get only unread mails then you have to store seen UID's(read mails) but that is not your requirement.Check once

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the email server which control what emails you can download. Just like gmail give following options for pop
    -   POP is enabled for all mail that has arrived since 5:36 pm
    -   Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)
    -   Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on