# Email account to make it outgoing and incoming email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

now i made website in mvc and through this website i'll retrieve and send emails by my email but i couldn't make that because of my wrong email configuration my email is G mail so i used this configuration in my website 
email , pasword , smtp server is smtp.gmail.com ,port number is 587 and make ssl true 
but i still couldn't retrieve or send email through my website because i need to change some settings in my Gmail but when i searched about that i didn't find how to use my current Gmail but i found use Gmail to adding other emails to it and i didn't understand that so if any body can help me in my problem,I will be thankful to him 
sorry about bad English

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056715/reading-emails-from-gmail-in-c-sharp

Comment: the problem isn't in my code @Luca cuz i used right configured Gmail and it's working right but when i need to make another email but the email not working i think the setting of this email is wrong but i searched a lot  how to configure Gmail to use it in website as incoming and out going but i didn't find any thing helpful

Comment: and thanks @luca for your reply and i wish to understand my problem to help me

Comment: however you should edit your question and add your code, so we can see which settings are you using and can help you @NOOR