# How to Parse email directly from gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, parsing, email-parsing

is there a way in c# / asp.net to directly parse the email that it receives from Gmail? I used pop3 server to receive the data from Gmail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056715/reading-emails-from-gmail-in-c-sharp

Comment: It is called web scrapping. So when you get a response from the website you need to parse the tags in the html string.