# access currently sent/received mails from gmail mailbox

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to access currently sent/received mails from mailbox. I had done some coding but it is not giving me only latest arrived mails in mailbox, it gives me 2 days old mails even if by applying filter to fire query of date as from-to and specifying to date as currently date on the system.
What should i do to get current mails from mailbox by applying filter of date and time.

```
dtTimeTo.Value = DateTime.Now;
string query = "after: " + fromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " before: " + toDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " label: " + labelName; 
UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
request.Q = query;
ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippet. Please show us.

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: I would use imap, check stackoverflow for imap+google. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056715/reading-emails-from-gmail-in-c-sharp)

Comment: dtTimeTo.Value = DateTime.Now;                                                                       string query = "after: " + fromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " before: " +
                                toDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " label: " + labelName;   UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
            request.Q = query;
            ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();

Comment: Try building up your string and then putting it in the search box in Gmail to test it you will be able to find errors easier that way **after: 2018/07/09 before: 2018/07/10 label:unread**