# Reading and Deleting Emails for automated Tests c#

Tags: c#, email, imap

I am running automated Tests on Azure Piplines, initially I was planing to read and delete Emails using Gmail API but for that I would need an service account (Because I cant authenticate it using oaut because its running on the Azure Pipline)

Now I am wondering whats the best solution to my problem, are there any other free mail services with an API?

Or am I able to read my Mails with an Imap library (without requiering oaut)

Comment: Don't so this in unit testing, it's unreliable. Better to mock out the SMTP sending, or have it save to local disk instead of sending.

Comment: Setting up your own IMAP server is dead easy.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

Allow Insecure Apps:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Send Emails (SMTP):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/707892/10637110

Read Emails (IMAP):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/10637110

Comment: Or better, generate an app specific password.  Or host your own SMTP and IMAP server for test purposes.

Comment: could you explain it in more detail, how do I do something like this?