# How to retrieve email from Gmail

Tags: c#, wpf, email, gmail

I have developed a WPF C# application. Sending email from the Gmail account is OK. But I need to receive all mail from the Gmail account.
Is there anyway to do this? How to do it? Using third party libraries is not a problem.
Thank you for reading...

Comment: Use `System.Net.Mail` as per this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: That question is based on *sending* email, not *receiving* email.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail support IMAP. You have to get a IMAP .NET library to read read your Gmail inbox.

here are few links, that I hope will help you

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101522/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-c-sharp)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp)