# Where do I begin to learn how to use pop3 and imap protocols with c#?

Tags: c#, email, imap, pop3

I want to read mails from Gmail without deleting them while reading.
However I want to have the option to delete a specific email.

Where do I begin?( I don't want to use others libraries - I want to start it from scratch)

Comment: If you are just looking at Gmail, you will find it far easier to use the RSS feeds provided.

Comment: I managed to read the mails using Atom Feed.
Is their any way using Atom Feed to delete mails?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this about IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c) and [this about POP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c), there is no built-in support for IMAP or POP in .Net. However, [there are a plethora of free (and open-source) utilities you can use.](http://www.google.com/#q=pop+imap+email+c%23)

Answer (score 0):

> There is no .NET framework support for
>   IMAP. You'll need to use some 3rd
>   party component.

This question and related questions have a list of libraries and links.
[Accessing Imap in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start at the basics start by reading the rfcs

RFC 3501 for IMAP

RFC 1939 & 2449 for POP3