# From where can we download the python dlls email, getpass, imaplib, os 

Tags: python

I am searching to download the python dlls email, getpass, imaplib, os and use that in vb.net to get the gmail email with attachments

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VB.net, I would look into some libraries written for the .NET platform.  Just googling for ".NET IMAP client" revealed several seemingly good links for a [Open Source .NET IMAP Client](http://koolwired.com/solutions/solutions.aspx?id=30), [IMAP Client library using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx) and [Accessing Imap in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have DLLs which you can simply use with VB.net. Your fundamental understanding of the modules libraries is flawed.

Comment: can you please tell me what are they i need to get the gmail email in vb.net. To read the gmail email attachment I saw using imablib

Comment: I don't know `VB.NET`. If you're using Python, you can use imaplib.

Comment: I used the commercial product to read the gmail email in VB.NEThttp://www.lesnikowski.com/

Comment: Looks like a simple IMAP/POP library. I'm sure there are open source libraries to do that but if lesnikowski works for you, I guess it's fine.