# How do I access IMAP in Windows 8 Store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, imap, windows-store-apps

Looking at creating a small email client for Windows 8 as a proof of concept. I've never actually written an email app, and it looks like I picked a difficult place to start, as System.Net.Mail seems to not be available to store apps.

[This thread about IMAP in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp) has lots of examples of libraries and components for doing IMAP in c#, but most of them seem to rely on functions not available in WinRT

Am I missing something obvious or do I just have to implement IMAP from the ground up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write your own implementation for IMAP/SMTP/POP3
Because Metro apps use a lot of sharing contracts. And microsoft says that if you want to write your own email client it is likely that they want their own implementation. If not just use a share contract with the build in Email client.

So I think the answer is. You need to write your own implementation of the [RFC 3501 - INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) or use Share contract to talk to your installed email client.

Comment: +1 for using the Share contract.

You could also use http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ or another library. https://github.com/kisli/vmime comes to mind, though you'd need a commercial license to use it on the MS Store. 

Would probably need a bit of modding, but in principle it could work.