# Retrieving an imap account mail and then displaying the mail in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap

this is more of a sighter as to what i will need to complete this..
 We have an intranet using asp.net, the idea is to retrieve mail and its attachments and then displaying this/these messages in a listbox/ or table of some description.
i will be using c# to compile this.
 
now the mail that is needed to be retrieved are faxes/from our fax account which we have setup in outlook atm, 
  -each of these faxes has an attachment. 
  -the attachment is a tiff file.
  -so the end result is to get at the tiff file and to have it listed.

im aware that there are librays/class's out there tha will need to be attached/referenced, so this can work.

at the moment i have a brief idea of what is needed for this but i would like a list if possible the items/things i need to have.. a checklist if you will.

i have a very crude first attempt. im using the S22.IMAP set of librays from 
 https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap

I take it this can be acheived someway or another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Exchange >= 2007, you can retrieve data via [Exchange Web Services (EWS)](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fexchange%2Fbb204119(v%3Dexchg.140).aspx&ei=vwihUIq1Naqm4gTkjIGgDg&usg=AFQjCNENsz7V5gNFR6QfT_7m0n3OunkOYQ&sig2=lb2BQqqlYfn7Yx6q2SUFjw) thus allowing your application to work without needing Outlook client on the system and all other issues with older-school approaches. I don't have any direct experience with EWS, but a co-worker tells me you can do whatever Outlook Web Access can.

**EDIT**

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp) addresses a similar issue, it's been answered with references to what I believe are the most popular libraries for IMAP.

Comment: hi Alex, thanks for your speedy reply.. we do not use exchange to connect to this account. the outlook account for this uses imap to connect.. our incoming and outgoing servers are the same in that sense. our server address for this is in effect an ip address. this imap is only setup on one client machine, so its restricted to that one user/machine.<br /> the idea is to get this so its displayed on out intranet so everybody who neeeds to, can view theses messages/faxes<br />please excuse me if i have misunderstood you.

Comment: @DanWood I dug up another SO question concerning the issue at hand, and appended the link