# Get all emails in inbox .Net.Mail C#

Tags: c#, email, system.net.mail

I'm making a small program that can send emails and read emails. I can currently send emails however I'm not sure how I can access my inbox using .Net.Mail. Is there a way of doing this?

My code is as fallows

```
try
{
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

    // set smtp-client with basicAuthentication
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@live.com", "password");
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    // add from,to mailaddresses
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("example@live.com");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@example.eu");
    MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
    MailMessage msg; 

    // set subject and encoding
    myMail.Subject = "Test message";
    myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    // set body-message and encoding
    myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
    myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    // text or html
    myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
}

catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException
        ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?  What is the issue?

Comment: If you want to access the stored email folders for Microsoft mail accounts consider the REST API @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations - POP won't cut it.

Comment: This is not possible with the framework's System.Net.Mail. You'll need a library like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) with IMAP or POP3 support.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get emails with SMTP. You need to use IMAP

Consider using a library like https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail AEMail

For more info go here:
[Accessing Imap in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Or there's also POP3

Comment: @PeterRitchie -- Yeah but who wants to use that anymore?

Comment: @rory.ap usually not about choice with some mail providers :(

Comment: @PeterRitchie True, true, we should inform our friend of all considerations.