# How to use ImapClient in c#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, imap

I want to be able to read emails from smtp in c#, and I have the the AE.Net.Mail library. I have the code from this thread

[Accessing Imap in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c-sharp)

but I get an error `ImapClient does not contain a definition for 'AuthMethods'`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the Code, that shows what u have tried to call the **AuthMethods** method?

Comment: I figured out that it's now `AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login`.

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: You cannot read emails from SMTP.  SMTP is for sending.  IMAP is for receiving.