# What methods are there for having .NET code run and handle e-mails as they arrive?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I've been tasked with creating some sort of service that will take any e-mail sent to an e-mail address and handle the contents of the e-mail (including binary attachments.)

I've got full access to the server (Windows Server 2008) that will run this service, and have decided to code the solution using the .NET framework (3.5).

Now I'm thinking about the different ways I can do this. Since I'm not very experienced in handling e-mails programmatically, the first solution that came into my head was to create an e-mail client that will periodically poll an existing e-mail server for incoming e-mail (using the POP3 protocol) and process them. But there are other ways to do it.

One could be to use IMAP to stay connected to the mail server and fetch e-mails as soon as they arrive (more responsive, but I believe the IMAP protocol is harder to implement.) The follow-up question here is: where can I find reliable e-mail libraries that support the POP3 or the IMAP protocol?

Another could be to somehow configure the e-mail server to directly pipe the e-mails sent to a specific address to my binary code (I've seen this done on Linux servers.) I have no idea how to go about this, though.

The last I can think of would be to create a dummy e-mail server on its own address that handles the e-mail directly as it arrives, but to me this seems like a bad idea.

Does anyone have experience in this area? I would imagine that having to write e-mail handlers for ticket support systems isn't that uncommon, all I need in addition to that is to handle the attachments.

I'd be grateful for any hints and tips.

Comment: I've found this: http://pop2ticket.codeplex.com/ which I'll be using as a starting point. I'd be very grateful for alternatives though.

Comment: Similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837052/receive-and-process-email-with-asp-net-c

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950835/coding-for-how-to-receive-a-mail-in-windows-apllication

Comment: A duplicate of a post made 5 months later than this one? If any post, it would be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/recommendations-for-a-net-component-to-access-an-email-inbox – If it's any help to future readers of this post, I ended up using MailBee.NET IMAP by AfterLogic (www.afterlogic.com)

Comment: @Blixt: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46183/time-for-a-spring-cleaning-in-the-dusty-corner-of-net-mail-reading.  Also, the "possible duplicate" comments are auto-generated now, which I'm not thrilled about.

Comment: @Blixt: don't take close votes personally - it's just a way to keep the system clean and the information useful. It's certainly possible to have a question be a duplicate of one posted later.

Comment: I understand, I'm not questioning the close-vote, I'm questioning the choice of "duplicated post". The 1950835 question was not only posted much later, but also of rather poor quality. I'd rather you voted this as a duplicate of 18006, directing people to that question, since it has more interesting content.

Comment: After reading this question more carefully, I see that it is *not* a duplicate of the generic "how to recieve mails in .NET" question. That said, I still think we have a possible duplicate, where the accepted answer happens to be MailBee.NET :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837052/receive-and-process-email-with-asp-net-c

Comment: Adding to my comment above: Yours is definately the better of the two questions (+1), so if we are allowed to have duplicates from the future (@Michael say that we are), I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837052 to be redirected here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with alot of things - it depends.  Ask yourself the following questions:

1. What are your latency requirements--do you need to process incoming messages as quickly as possible, or can processing be batched?  If it can be batched, then how often would you have to process the "inbox"?
2. What are your throughput requirements?  How many messages are we talking about per minute here?  How big are the messages?  This would affect the decision you make about polling interval if using a batch scenario;
3. What sort of e-mail system are you integrating with?  If it's Exchange, what programmatic interfaces are available to access a mailbox?  Until the most recent version of Exchange, interestingly enough, there were issues with accessing a mailbox on an Exchange server (The client-side CDO COM components needed to be used which is not ideal---and there were security limitations).

By far the simplest approach is to poll a mailbox using POP3.  However, if you need to respond *immediately* to an incoming message, then this isn't going to cut it.

As far as possible *avoid* writing your own SMTP service--it's been done a thousand times before and you're just creating unnecessary work for yourself and exposing yourself to security threats.  If you *absolutely have to* respond immediately to messages, then rather set up an instance of [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/) or [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) to spawn a process that you have written.

If you're going to go for the POP3 solution (it looks like you are), then have a read of related questions "[Free POP3 .NET library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606/free-pop3-net-library)" and "[Reading Email using POP3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)".

Comment: There are no real latency requirements, although it would be nice to process them as they arrive to spread out CPU usage as much as possible. This won't be a server that will get much throughput. There will be a few usage spikes (this is for a contest), but after that, use will be pretty low. Messages will be up to 1 MB each (they include a short mobile video.) The e-mail system to integrate with hasn't been decided yet, but I don't think it will be Exchange. And finally, I intend to do this with as much code reuse as possible so pointers to libraries are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've used webdav in the past with c# to access an exchange server periodically and process emails.

This has worked quite well, and I'd probably use that method again if I need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the .net components from http://www.quiksoft.com/ might help with your requirement.

The app polls a POP3 mail server every x minutes(s) and works it's way through the messages in the queue, and deletes them when it's processed each msg.

The QuikSoft tools also provide ways to parse the emails to get the content from each msg.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving the email is not the hardest part, parsing, extracting attachments is.

If any one is interested in commercial product take a look at Mail.dll.
It supports IDLE command you have mentioned for [instant notifications](http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/imap-idle/).

Mail.dll includes **POP3**, **IMAP** clients and powerful MIME parser:

```
using(Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("imap.server.com");
    imap.Login("user", "password");

    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uidList = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.Unseen);
    foreach (long uid in uidList)
    {
        IMail mail = new MailBuilder()
            .CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(uid));
        Console.WriteLine(mail.Subject);
    }
    imap.Close(true);
}
```

Please note that this is commercial product that I've created.

You can download it at [http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/)