# Is there an "event" fired upon email reception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email

Is there a way to be notified when an email is received?

I want my website to perform some actions upon receiving an email. Is polling the email server the only way, or is there some way to get notified of a new email?

Comment: Depends on your mail server, because the receiving party must act. So if you have an exchange server, you could build a plugin for it that call an url of your site for example. If you mail is @outlook/hotmail/live you do need to poll.

Comment: @SynerCoder I have a shared-hosted website and email address. I don't I have much custom control over it.

Comment: This is not enough information - what email server are you using ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar The website is on iis, so I would assume the email server as well. All I know is that I can access it via POP3, IMAP, and SMTP.

Comment: See [What methods are there for having .NET code run and handle e-mails as they arrive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243557/what-methods-are-there-for-having-net-code-run-and-handle-e-mails-as-they-arriv).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. It seems email servers don't (usually?) have that functionality built-in. Oh well, looks like polling it is.