# Program for fetching email from the inbox in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, email, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendations for a .NET component to access an email inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/recommendations-for-a-net-component-to-access-an-email-inbox)

I am trying to develop an application to parse email messages. I wrote that program in PHP. It is now working. But the problem is I can not complete my requirement. Now I try to do this in VB.NET or any type of language that is supported by Visual Studio. My actual requirement is fetch the email and the link contained in the email.

If possible, sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want. Your working php code would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx.
If you need SSL (for Gmail for example) - then here is an example for you. I wrote it a while ago, and it's based on some code I found on 
the Internet. (Sorry can't remember where - so no attribution)

```
public class Pop3EMail
{
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public long Bytes { get; set; }
    public bool Retrieved { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
public class SecurePop3Client : TcpClient, IDisposable
{
    SslStream netStream;
    static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SecurePop3Client));

    private SecurePop3Client()
    { }

    private void EstablishConnection(string serverAddress, int port, string sertificateName, string username, string password)
    {

        try
        {
            Connect(serverAddress, port);

            netStream = new SslStream(GetStream());

            netStream.AuthenticateAsClient(sertificateName);

            CheckResponse(GetServerResponse());
            CheckResponse(SendToServer(string.Format("USER {0}\r\n", username)));
            CheckResponse(SendToServer(string.Format("PASS {0}\r\n", password)));
            log.DebugFormat("Connected to {0}:{1}, with serificate :{2}", serverAddress, port, sertificateName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new SecurePop3Exception("Connecting to Email server failed", e);
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        CheckResponse(SendToServer("QUIT\r\n"));
        log.Debug("Disconnected from server");
    }


    public List<Pop3EMail> List()
    {
        string response;
        var ret = new List<Pop3EMail>();
        CheckResponse(SendToServer("LIST\r\n"));
        while (true)
        {
            response = GetServerResponse();
            if (response == ".\r\n")
            {
                log.DebugFormat("Retrieved {0} messages from the server", ret.Count);
                return ret;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] values = response.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                    Pop3EMail mail = new Pop3EMail
                    {
                        Number = Int32.Parse(values[0]),
                        Bytes = Int32.Parse(values[1]),
                        Retrieved = false
                    };
                    ret.Add(mail);
                }
                // catch (ArgumentNullException)
                // catch (FormatException)
                // catch (OverflowException)
                // catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new SecurePop3Exception("Parsing message list failed", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void RetrieveBody(Pop3EMail mail)
    {
        string response;

        CheckResponse(SendToServer(string.Format("RETR {0}\r\n", mail.Number)));

        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            response = GetServerResponse();
            if (response == ".\r\n")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                body.Append(response);
            }
        }
        mail.Retrieved = true;
        mail.Body = body.ToString();
        log.DebugFormat("Retrieved body of mail {0}", mail.Number);
    }


    public void Delete(Pop3EMail mail)
    {
        CheckResponse(SendToServer(string.Format("DELE {0}\r\n", mail.Number)));
        log.DebugFormat("Deleted Email {0}", mail.Number);
    }

    private string GetServerResponse()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buff = new Byte[2];
            int bytes = netStream.Read(buff, 0, 1);
            if (bytes == 1)
            {
                buffer[count] = buff[0];
                count++;

                if (buff[0] == '\n')
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            };
        };

        string retval = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
        log.DebugFormat("GOT FROM SERVER: {0}",retval);
        return retval;
    }


    private string SendToServer(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            log.DebugFormat("SEND TO SERVER: {0}", message);
            return GetServerResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           throw new SecurePop3Exception(string.Format("Communication with server failed"), e);
        }
    }

    private void CheckResponse(string response)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) || response.Length < 3 || string.Compare(response.Substring(0, 3),"+OK",true) != 0)
        {
            throw new SecurePop3Exception(response);
        }
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Factory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverAddress"></param>
    /// <param name="port"></param>
    /// <param name="sertificateName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SecurePop3Client Connect(string serverAddress, int port, string sertificateName, string username, string password)
    {
        SecurePop3Client client = new SecurePop3Client();
        client.EstablishConnection(serverAddress, port, sertificateName, username, password);
        return client;
    }



    #region Dispose Design Pattern Implementation
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">if set to <c>true</c> [disposing].</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Disconnect();
            netStream.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
    ~SecurePop3Client()
    {
        // Simply call Dispose(false).
        Dispose(false);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: thaks sir for this excellent. i will try with this .....

Answer (score 1):

There is a fantastic resource in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) for this sort of thing. I've used this [POP3 example project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/pop3client.aspx) for C#.