# C# / asp.net: What are your views on .net email components/suites out there?

Tags: c#, email

Found two libraries Rebex ([www.rebex.net](http://www.rebex.net)) and QuikSoft ([www.quiksoft.com](http://www.quiksoft.com)) any comments on these based on experience or other ones I havent not found?

Looking for components that will use SMTP to send a lot of emails for general email notificatins and bulk mailshots. Built in templating would be nice. Also need to receive emails from various accounts. Having the ability to validate and check bounce backs etc would be good for reporting (appreciating that this isnt 100% effective)

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as your requirements from such a suite. Why do you need one and System.Net.Mail is not enough etc...

Comment: System.Net.Mail is fine for sending emails and does work well, if we buy in a mail suite, should we continue with System.Nte.Mail? are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question doesn't provide too much detail on what the usage is going to be, it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/recommendations-for-a-net-component-to-access-an-email-inbox) stackoverflow question sums up quite some options.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(not mentioned in the link provided by Thomas)</sub>

We use [MailBee](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) in out product and have had no problems with it.