# How To Receiving Email In VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, pop3, email-client

Hi friends,
I've done a project in VB.Net about sending e-mails, and I'm trying to Receive e-mails as well, is there any references i should read to get the job done.

Comment: Look at the SmtpClient class for querying smtp servers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx Also, capitalizing every word of your question makes it harder to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendations for a .NET component to access an email inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/recommendations-for-a-net-component-to-access-an-email-inbox)

Comment: this is not an answer to his question, i believe he was asking about (Receiving e-mails) not sending e-mails .