# How to check email using a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, pop3

I am looking for a vb.net code for receiving e-mails without using any 3rd party libraries. I want to check Unread messages, Inbox and Sent messages. A Working sample is appreciated.

What is the default port for SMTP , is it port 25 (is it the same for all SMTP mail servers?).  Which is more flexible in my case POP3 or IMAP ?

Edit: 
**Someone please give me a sample working code for receiving mail using [lumisoft](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/Download/Downloads/Net/) (pop) in vb.net**

Comment: Have a look at this duplicate [Recommendations for a .NET component to access an email inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/recommendations-for-a-net-component-to-access-an-email-inbox) It is for C# not VB.Net, but for this question the important thing is the choice of component, and those components can be used from VB just as easily as from C#. I'm voting to close your question, please don't take that personally. It just means I think your question is a duplicate of that other question. On StackOverflow we like to close duplicate questions to keep things organised.

Comment: No don't close this, I am unable to find a working code anywhere else.

Comment: This is a scrap note for receiving response from mail clients :
http://evry1falls.freevar.com/VBNet/VS2010DataBaseBook/vbnetpop3.html
really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From lumisoft Help.

```
/*
 To make this code to work, you need to import following namespaces:
 using LumiSoft.Net.Mime;
 using LumiSoft.Net.POP3.Client; 
 */

using(POP3_Client c = new POP3_Client()){
    c.Connect("ivx",WellKnownPorts.POP3);
    c.Authenticate("test","test",true);

    // Get first message if there is any
    if(c.Messages.Count > 0){
        // Do your suff

        // Parse message
        Mime m = Mime.Parse(c.Messages[0].MessageToByte());
        string from = m.MainEntity.From;
        string subject = m.MainEntity.Subject;            
        // ... 
    }        
}
```

Comment: How do I implement lumisoft in vb.net ? I mean I need to reference its .Net files some place in vb.net , How am I suppose to do that

Answer (score 0):

Pop is more supported and most servers have it on if you want to implement your own pop service a good place to start is the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939).

Comment: rfc is a 3rd party library ?  anyways how do I implement  it , I am new to .Net